# UILabel Word Wrap produces non-uniform spacing between words

Tags: ios, objective-c, line-breaks

I have a `UILabel` in a `UITableViewCell` that displays content generated from an API. The Label is set to be multiline and with autolayout constraints such that the leading spacer is set to be equal to a specific number and the trailing spacer is set to be greater than or equal to a specific number. I have the line break mode set to word wrap. Unfortunately, that is producing the following:

[image: pic1]

but also the following in the same table view:

[image: pic2]

As you can see the spacing is uneven. I can't use character break as the line break mode, so I am wondering what I have done wrong or how I can get a word-break line wrapping mode that is not changing the width of the white space between words.Is this possible with UILabel? If not what do I need to do?

Comment: Almost looks like you have the justification set to "fill" instead of "left."

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: What text alignment you use?